# NativeScript: How to get all elements having a certain class

Tags: javascript, android, css, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to get all elements in my XML (NativeScript with Vue) that have the same class. Is this possible?

As an extension, is it possible to add custom attributes to existing controls like the `TextField` (similar to `data-*` attributes in HTML), and if so, is there a selector that I could use to get all elements having the same `data-` attribute? (For example, the HTML/CSS equivalent would be something like `input[data-customerid="12"]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something like `document.querySelector(...)`, there is a paid plugin - [nativescript-dom](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-dom). FYI, you might find the free / unmaintained version on Github, which is not guaranteed to work with {N} v6.x or later.

If you are looking for [Attribute CSS selectors](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#attribute-selector), that's supported out of the box. And Yes, you can add custom attributes in XML.